# Why does the following cause a stack overflow?

Tags: javascript

The following function is designed to block macrotasks, by repeatedly creating microtasks using `await`.

But why does it cause a stack overflow?

I thought `await` would put the recursive call on a microtask, and therefore empty the stack (clearly I was wrong).

```js
const waitUsingMicroTasks = async (durationMs, start = performance.now()) => {
    const wait = async () => {
        let elapsed = (performance.now() - start)
        if(elapsed < durationMs) await wait()
    }
    await wait()
}

waitUsingMicroTasks(1000)
```

Whereas this - which I thought was almost equivalent - does not cause a stackoverflow:

```js
const waitUsingMicroTasks = async (durationMs, start = performance.now()) => {
    const wait = async () => {
        let elapsed = (performance.now() - start)
        if(elapsed < durationMs) Promise.resolve().then(wait)
    }
    await wait()
}

waitUsingMicroTasks(1000)
```

Comment: The difference between start and performance.now() is most likely 0, so the function will call itself immediately continuously.

Comment: Sure. The purpose of the (silly) function is to block macrotasks. But microtasks are asynchronous and do provide "cooperative multitasking" (if you know what I mean).

Comment: This is a problem on many systems, the processor and what you are trying to do will almost certainly be faster than the resolution of the clock, try using a counter instead and come up with a number of iterations instead.

Comment: But... I expect a completely new stack with each indirect recursive call. So memory will increase, but I don't expect stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recursive function is resolving entirely within the same microtask.

A new microtask is created when an `await` is encountered, you're correct. But the `await` operator needs to have a Promise or value in order to implicitly wrap it in a new Promise and attach callbacks. This means the value being `await`ed *needs to be evaluated first* before it can be scheduled as a microtask.

However, each execution of `wait` can't obtain a Promise to `await` before calling the next `wait`. So actually the stack is overflowing synchronously with no microtask being scheduled. You never actually obtain a Promise, because each Promise is dependent on the next one to be evaluated - each `wait()` call happens synchronously after the last one before any `await`s are resolved.

You might be able to force a microtask by `await`ing some value that does not need recursive calls to be evaluated:

```
const waitUsingMicroTasks = async (durationMs, start = performance.now()) => {
    const wait = async () => {
        let elapsed = await (performance.now() - start)
        if(elapsed < durationMs) await wait()
    }
    await wait()
}

waitUsingMicroTasks(1000)
```

In your second example, this problem does not exist because you explicitly create a Promise and attach `wait` as a callback to it. This way, `wait` is not immediately executed (like with the `await`) but it is called when the Promise.resolve() microtask is run, some time later.

Comment: Good one. Nice explanation. So how can I replicate the second implementation, but using `await`?

Comment: @52d6c6af The crux of the issue is that each execution of `wait` synchronously incurs another execution of `wait`. You need to defer execution of `wait()` until after the microtask is run, which necessarily means making it a callback. I think the only way you can do that is by `await`ing something else first before the `wait()` call as in my example.

Comment: I have found this seems to work: `if(elapsed < durationMs) await 1 && await wait()`

Comment: ...and this seems to work too: `if(elapsed < durationMs) ((await 1), wait())`

Comment: So does this mean that the expression  to the right of an `await` is immediately run, synchronously, equivalent to the executor function of a `Promise` constructor?

Comment: @52d6c6af Yes, that's correct - the `await`ed expression is evaluated immediately, and then a Promise callback is attached to it that runs the rest of the code pending execution after the `await`ed Promise resolves. Any way that you're able to put the `wait()` call in that pending code will work to stop the synchronous stack overflow.

Comment: But surely it depends on whether the `await` is the first in the `async` function, because the expressions on the RHS of subsequent `awaits` are certainly not evaluated until the first `await` has resolved?

Comment: @52d6c6af Subsequent `await`s count as "pending code" in that case. Basically the first `await` evaluates whatever value it needs to wait for, and sticks all the rest of the function that hasn't been evaluated yet into the implicit callback that will run after the `await`ed value has resolved. So you're right, subsequent `await`ed values aren't evaluated yet, they get stuck into that callback.

Comment: OK interesting. So the behavior of `await` actually depends on the position in the code relative to other `await`s.

Comment: @52d6c6af Just to clarify: The first `await` doesn't *immediately* evaluate its operand, it does when it's actually encountered in the code, like pretty much most other operators. Check out the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) page to refresh. `await` is just a unary operator, when it's encountered its operand needs to be evaluated before `await` can do its thing.

Comment: I think the 2nd line of your answer needs clarification, because although a microtask is created when an `await` is encountered, it is filled with the continuation, rather than the RHS expression.

Answer (score 1):

Klaycon's answer pretty much covers everything, but it's very easy to observe that all of your calls to `wait` are happening synchronously (on the stack):

```js
const waitUsingMicroTasks = async (durationMs, start = performance.now()) => {
    let i = 0;

    const wait = async () => {
        console.log(i);
        i += 1;
        (i < 20) &&  (await wait());
    }

    wait();

    console.log('done');
}

waitUsingMicroTasks(5000)
```

You can see here that all the `console.log(i)`s take place before `console.log('done')`, so `wait()` isn't running asynchronously at all.

As Klaycon indicates, awaiting something that's not a recursive call to `wait` seems to solve this, but one other approach you could take is to await something that's actually asynchronous, like a `setTimeout`:

```js
const waitUsingMicroTasks = async (durationMs, start = performance.now()) => {
    let i = 0;
    console.log('starting', new Date());
    while ((performance.now() - start) < durationMs) {
        await Promise.resolve();
    }
    console.log('done', new Date());
}

waitUsingMicroTasks(5000);
console.log('after wait');
```

Comment: `await`ing a `setTimeout` is not particularly useful in this example, because that would elevate the delays to the level of macrotasks, and the aim of this function is to block on microtasks.

Comment: @52d6c6af Ok, good point. However, it remains the case that I don't think there's a  need to use a convoluted recursive function for this. All you need is a loop and an `await`. Apparently, `await 1` would suffice, but `await Promise.resolve()` would ensure that you're actually awaiting a promise. Edited my answer.

Comment: `await 1` is equivalent to `await Promise.resolve(1)`?

Comment: @52d6c6af I wouldn't say they're identical, but it seems that any use of `await` places a task on the microqueue and waits for it, so awaiting a constant value should probably suffice. Can't say that with 100% certainty, though.

Comment: `await 1` is equivalent to `new Promise((resolve) => resolve(1))` AFIK. The important bit is what comes next (I have learned in this question). The code immediately after the RHS of `await` is put in a `.then` callback, which will be scheduled on the next microtask. My understanding. My earlier misunderstanding was that the RHS of `await` was scheduled on a microtask, which is not the case. Your loop implementation is cleaner than my recursive implementation.

Comment: @52d6c6af _"The code immediately after the RHS of await is put in a .then callback"_ Not sure what  you mean by "immediately after" but I think a better wording would be "the result of fully evaluating the RHS of `await` is awaited using a microtask". So if you had `await 1 + 2`, you would be awaiting `3`, not the unevaluated expression `1 + 2`. In this sense, `await` works like basically any other operator in the sense that its operands (or in this case, operand) is evaluated to a value before it actually does anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are no blocking tasks done in the function. So it will keep executing the next recursion almost immediately, and since there is no recursion escape results in stack overflow.

Introducing a time consuming tasks like console log into the code and it will run fine.

```
let count=0;
const waitUsingMicroTasks = async (durationMs, start = performance.now()) => {
    const wait = async () => {
        let elapsed = (performance.now() - start);
        console.log(++count);
        (elapsed < durationMs) &&  (await wait());
    }
    await wait();  
}

waitUsingMicroTasks(1000)
```

Comment: OK thank you. But this finding still confuses me. Because `await` queues up a microtask, the stack should be fresh each time. I don't understand how introducing a delay avoids the stack overflow.

Comment: @52d6c6af Introducing a delay only limits the number of recursive calls that can be made before `durationMs` is reached. This only works because 1000 ms is relatively small. It's not actually helping to clear the stack.

Comment: Also, this doesn't at all accomplish what OP is trying to do because it simply blocks the main thread until enough time has passed. There is no scheduling of tasks until after that time has elapsed.